# How to redirect a page in perl script

Tags: perl

I am fairly new to Perl.

I have a form that reads into a script.pl and does the validation check and etc.

How can I make it so once its done showing the validation, loops back to the home page after a few seconds automatically?

I tried using the following and it didn't work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $url = "http://google.com";
print "Location: $url\n\n";
```

An Example of HTML for this would be: `<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="10;URL=index.htm">`

---

here is what i have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings; 
my $url = "google.com";; 
print "Location: $url\n\n"; 
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
%form=&parse_form(); 

etc....etc...
```

Comment: works for me. Did you include `#!/usr/bin/perl` as the first line?

Comment: please see above for how i have it.

Comment: There is a perl module called CGI, see ``perldoc CGI``

Comment: you might need `\r\n` instead.  why do you keep going after you print the `Location` header?  also how are you learning perl?  `&` to call a function is _ancient_.

Comment: @Vorsprung is right about using CGI. You should be modifying the header to send the new location directive, as well as change the http status to 302. This also should be only sent to the browser after your validations are finished. This gives an example of what the response should look like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302 edit: no idea why this almost 6 year old question got on the homepage